# Hedging exchange rate risk from ADR with FX Forwards

Tags: fx, hedge

Is there a more efficient way of hedging exchange rate risk from ADRs instead of constantly trading FX Forwards? How does the industry usually hedge that risk?

Moreover, is it reasonable to suppose that the value of every ADR of European stocks is equally sensitive to changes in the EURUSD rate?

I'd appreciate suggestions of papers which address these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The P&L of an ADR/GDR comes from the changes in the underlying equity price denominated in local currency, and from the changes in the currency exchange rate. You net by currency the FX delta of all your ADR positions (long, short, options...), and if it exceeds your appetite, then the simplest instrument to hedge it away is an FX forward - generally, physical delivery for developed markets, but non-delivery (NDF) for some emerging markets currencies. As long as the forward's maturity is no more than a few months, the P&L from the foreign currency interest rate is immaterial, and you just have an FX delta hedge. As the maturity date of a physical delivery forward or  the determination date of the NDF approaches, the FX delta goes away, so you need to roll - replace it with a new forward.

The biggest practical problem is that the FX delta from the ADRs will change whenever the underlying equity  price changes. Depending on how little FX delta you want to keep, you may need to re-hedge it often. It is a little easier but not required to add new forwards with the same maturity as some existing forward, so you have fewer maturities to remember to roll.

Depending on the currencies, you may consider using some FX futures in addition to forwards.

Depending on the currencies, instead of hedging delta, you may prefer to use out of the money FX options to hedge only a very adverse FX rate movement, and to keep the rest of the FX exposure.